# How to reduce Elapsed time for unit test

Tags: mysql, sql-server, unit-testing

I've created one test method which fetch data from database, but it takes approximately 20 sec. to execute. but I want to run this in less time, is it possible?

Comment: Hard to say without any code. How does the test method look like? How is the data fetched? How much data is fetched?

Comment: What are you trying to test? Typically in a unit test you are supposed to separate the code under test from any dependencies, including database. If you want to test the sql code use a tSQL tests for that.